# Wait for firebase user info to be loaded before using router guard

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am using:

```
vue@3.2.47
pinia@2.0.35
vue-router@4.1.6
```

I am using firestore authentication to authenticate a user and I am using firestore database to store more information about the user. I have some issues understanding the flow process and I managed to get something working but I don't think it is very efficient. Could you please review and tell me how I can make sure I am not making too many accesses to firestore for nothing?

The problem is as follow. I have 2 different cases:

1. I connect to the website by entering the url
2. I go through navigation and I use the router vue to go from one page to the other which doesn't reload the whole application.

I need in both cases to make sure that I have the access to the pinia store for the user meaning, I need the UID of the user who is logged in, his email, his phone number, ... Because I have a lot more information, I need to have also a user document in firestore database and can not only rely on firestore authentication.

I get the data as follow:
storeAuth pinia Store

```
export const useStoreAuth = defineStore('storeAuth', () => {
  const user = ref<User | null>(null)
  const profileStore = useProfileStore()


  const init = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
          await profileStore.getUserInfo(firebaseUser.uid)
          user.value = {
            id: firebaseUser.uid,
            email: firebaseUser.email,
            firstName: profileStore.firstName,
            lastName: profileStore.lastName,
            phone: profileStore.phone,
            streetAndNumber: profileStore.streetAndNumber,
            city: profileStore.city,
            postalCode: profileStore.postalCode,
            nationality: profileStore.nationality,
            gender: profileStore.gender
          }
          //console.log('logged in:',user.value);
        } else {
          user.value = null
          //console.log('logged out');
        }
        unsubscribe()
        resolve(user.value)
      })
    })
  }
...
```

profile pinia store

```
export const useProfileStore = defineStore('profile', () => {
  const firstName = ref<string>('')
  const lastName = ref<string>('')
  const phone = ref<string>('')
  const dob = ref<string[]>([])
  const streetAndNumber = ref<string>('')
  const city = ref<string>('')
  const postalCode = ref<string>('')
  const nationality = ref<string>('')
  const gender = ref<string>('')

  async function getUserInfo(uid:string) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "members", uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      firstName.value = docSnap.data().firstName
      lastName.value = docSnap.data().lastName
      phone.value = docSnap.data().phone
      dob.value = docSnap.data().dob
      streetAndNumber.value = docSnap.data().streetAndNumber
      city.value = docSnap.data().city
      postalCode.value = docSnap.data().postalCode
      nationality.value = docSnap.data().nationality
      gender.value = docSnap.data().gender
      return
    }
  }
...
```

And in my router, I am doing this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to) => {
  const storeAuth = useStoreAuth()
  await storeAuth.init()

  if (
    storeAuth.user &&
    (to.name === 'signin' || to.name === 'register' || to.name === 'request-password-rest')
  ) {
    return { name: 'home' }
  } else {
    return
  }
})
```

So in my router, before each routing, I wait for the storeAuth.init() function. It is working as expected and the application runs where I have always access to the logged in user but it also means that each time I connect to the application or go to another page within the app, I execute this function which makes a call to firebase Auth and also to Firebase database to get the user data. I don't know how I can make sure this is loaded only  at the start of the app and that the router view is waiting for it to be finished before executing the first router guard?